# specify a time period to make API requests and allow the user to stop and restart these requests in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval

I am learning React Native and I am working in an app. I spent some days now trying to find a way to do this:

I have a simple app with buttons. I need to record audio and send it to an API every 5 seconds. (in the code you will see 6 seconds)

I need to give the user the hability to stop the sending of audio, I thought that this could be accomplished by pressing buttons to change a state that would stop the communication with the API.

Here is my reasoning.

```
export default function App() {
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState();
  ...

  const uploadAudio = async (path) => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    ...

  async function startStreamRec () {

    if (stream) {

    try {
      const repet= setInterval(async ()=> { 

        await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    });

    const recording = new Audio.Recording();

      
      await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(Audio.RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY);
      await recording.startAsync(); 
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');



    console.log(disable);
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    setRecording(undefined);
    recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    const uri = recording.getURI(); 
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
    setPath(uri);
    uploadAudio(uri);

        }, 6000);


    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }

    } else {
      clearInterval(repet);
    }
  } 
    async function stopStream() {
      setStream(false);
      startStreamRec();
    }

 async function startStream() {
      setStream(true);
      startStreamRec();
    }

  return (
<View>
    ...
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={startStream} style={styles.cathButton}>
      <Text> Start</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ stopStream } style={styles.cathButton}>
        <Text> Stop </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

       ...
  
      

    </View>
  );
}
```

However, this code doenst is not working properly.

I have tryied some things with useeffect, with state hooks, while cycles of settimeout, setState but everything failed. A common error I'm getting is " error: too many re-renders. react limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.